# How to determine how a (downloaded) byte string is encoded in python?

Tags: python, decode, encode

I am trying to download a file and write it to disk, but somehow I am lost in encoding decoding land.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "http://export.arxiv.org/e-print/supr-con/9608001"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data = response.read()
    filename = 'test.txt'
    file_ = open(filename, 'wb')
    file_.write(data)
    file_.close()
```

Here data is a byte string. If I check the file I find a bunch of strange characters. I tried

```
import chardet
the_encoding = chardet.detect(data)['encoding']
```

but this results in None. So I don't really know how the data I downloaded is encoded?

If I just type "http://export.arxiv.org/e-print/supr-con/9608001" into the browser, it downloads a file that I can view with a text editor and it's a perfectly fine .tex file.

Comment: Your `data` contains file signature `b'\x1f\x8b'` i.e. GZIP compressed file…

Comment: check `print( response.headers )` and you see `Content-Encoding: x-gzip`  which shows that it sends data compressed with `gzip` (to send it faster) and you have to uncompress it. And when you run URL in browser then browser automatically uncompresses it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [`python-magic` library](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic).

> `python-magic` is a Python interface to the `libmagic` file type
> identification library. `libmagic` identifies file types by checking
> their headers according to a predefined list of file types. This
> functionality is exposed to the command line by the Unix command
> `file`.

*Commented* script (works on Windows 10, Python 3.8.6):

```
# stage #1: read raw data from a url
from urllib.request import urlopen
import gzip
url = "http://export.arxiv.org/e-print/supr-con/9608001"
with urlopen(url) as response:
    rawdata = response.read()

# stage #2: detect raw data type by its signature
print("file signature", rawdata[0:2])
import magic
print( magic.from_buffer(rawdata[0:1024]))

# stage #3: decompress raw data and write to a file
data = gzip.decompress(rawdata)
filename = 'test.tex'
file_ = open(filename, 'wb')
file_.write(data)
file_.close()

# stage #4: detect encoding of the data ( == encoding of the written file)
import chardet
print( chardet.detect(data))
```

**Result**: `.\SO\68307124.py`

```
file signature b'\x1f\x8b'
gzip compressed data, was "9608001.tex", last modified: Thu Aug  8 04:57:44 1996, max compression, from Unix
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
```